# Error in Paypal authentication in Sandbox mode : Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5.4, paypal-sandbox, laravel-5.5

## **[Reference](http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5/link)**

**Code**

```
public function ShowPaymentWithPaypal()
{
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
    $item_1 = new Item();
    $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice(2); /** unit price **/

    $item_list = new ItemList();
    $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal(2);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($item_list)
        ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

    $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(\URL::route('ReturnedFromPaypal')) /** Specify return URL **/
        ->setCancelUrl(\URL::route('CancelledPaymentWithPaypal'));

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('Sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; **/

    try {
        $payment->create($this->_api_context);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        dd($ex);
        if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
            \Session::put('error','Connection timeout');
            return "Error occured";
            /** echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL; **/
            /** $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true); **/
            /** exit; **/
        } else {
            \Session::put('error','Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
            return "Error occured";
            /** die('Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient'); **/
        }
    }
    foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
    }
    /** add payment ID to session **/
    \Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
    if(isset($redirect_url)) {
        /** redirect to paypal **/
        return \Redirect::away($redirect_url);
    }
    \Session::put('error','Unknown error occurred');
    return "Last line error";
}
```

## **What's the problem ?**

When I try to do the login for doing payment using sandbox credentials, I get the below error.

> We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at
>   this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different
>   payment method.

**[I am following this to configure Paypal in Laravel 5.5](http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5/link)**

**XHR Error Details**

[image]
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you using a package for this, or have you manually written all the code?

Comment: I followed this: http://learninglaravel.net/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4-laravel-5/link

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a Paypal limitation.

In this [link](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Limits-and-verification/The-recipient-has-exceeded-the-receiving-limit-and-must-provide/td-p/881535?profile.language=en-gb), for example, the support say that Russia laws limit paypal account to 100000 rub of transaction.

When you reach the limit, you must specify something on your activities to unlock the limit.

Maybe have you reached the limit of transactions' amount for your country?
Try to use low amount, as 0.01 and to delete old test transactions from the sandbox account (seller).

If you haven't a lot of transactions for the seller, maybe the problem is in the customer's account?  Try to create a new account and use it.

I suppose in the sandbox will be a place to unlock the